# Cordova 2.5.0 & Android Lollipop 5.x.x & Sencha CMD 3.1.2.342

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

Has anyone had or heard of any android applications not working correctly in Android 5 (Lollipop)? One of my applications stopped displaying modules after it had been in production for a year. It only happens on phones with Android 5.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Cmd and Cordova version I guess that you are using old version of Sencha Touch.

As the Android 5 is new system, there might be changes which break some features of the old framework. Or something can behave differently than on older systems.

---

If it's bug in your app, you will need to rewrite it to support Android 5. Or if it's a bug in the framework, you will need to upgrade it.

Android 5 should be supported from Sencha **Touch 2.4.2** as well as on newer versions of Cordova.

I would suggest to try upgrade your app to the newer version of Sencha Touch. ( Although in some apps this might be complicated ).
And try to build it with newer version of Cordova.